# List 'n' number of posts from a Tag, each with a different class or ID

Tags: tags, get-posts

I want to list 'n' number of posts (ordered by latest first) -- post's title linked to the post's permalink -- from a tag on my WordPress blog. I also want to assign each link its own class or ID.

I checked this doc on [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), which is very relevant to what I need, but makes little sense to me (and I'm therefore unable to modify it to my needs).

Hope I am clear enough, if not, I can try to clarify.

**EDIT:** Just so it's clear, I want to be able to list the posts wherever I want. Any template.

Comment: Get any theme and look inside (Twenty Eleven for example). You will find there all you need.

Comment: @Alexey Oh, thanks, I will check. But please note that I want to define the number of posts I want to show, and assign a different class to each post. I don't think any theme has it like that, but I will check anyway.

Comment: Is the main loop (on your taxonomy-term archive page)? Or is a secondary loop in a template page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know PHP, so'll try to explain after showing you the example PHP code that's needed to do what's asked in the question.

**CODE:**

```
<!-- Featured Posts -->
<div id="featured-posts">
<?php
    $count = 0;
    $some_featured_posts = new WP_Query(array('tag' => 'example2', 'posts_per_page' => 7));
    while ($some_featured_posts->have_posts()): 
        $some_featured_posts->the_post();
        $count++;
?>
        <div class="featured-posts-wrapper<?php echo $count; ?> featured-posts-wrapper<?php echo ($count == 7) ? ' no-margin-right' : ''; ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img id="featured<?php echo $count; ?>" class="featured" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', true); ?>" /></a>
            <a id="featured-text<?php echo $count; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </div>
<?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>
<!-- Featured Posts -->
```

**PS:** I've included the div tags and classes hoping that they'll help the clueless. So, first put the code in a template, and check how and what it outputs, to get a better idea.

**EXPLANATION:**

- Add the code in any template of your choice (header.php, index.php, home.php, archive.php, search.php, content.php, or any other). That's where you'll see the output.
- Change the number (`7`) in this line to a number that's equal to the number of posts you want it to show:

  ```
  $some_featured_posts = new WP_Query(array('tag' => 'example2', 'posts_per_page' => 7));
  ```

  In the above code, the `'tag' => 'example2'` says that the latest posts tagged "example2" are to be shown. If you want to have a category instead, use `'category_name' => 'example2'`
- In this line:

  ```
  <div class="featured-posts-wrapper<?php echo $count; ?> featured-posts-wrapper<?php echo ($count == 7) ? ' no-margin-right' : ''; ?>">
  ```

  I use `class="featured-posts-wrapper<?php echo $count; ?>` so that I can have a different class for each post that's output. To be specific, the code above outputs as `class="featured-posts-wrapper1"` for the first post, `class="featured-posts-wrapper2"` for the second post, and so on.

  On the other hand, `<?php echo ($count == 7) ? ' no-margin-right' : ''; ?>` allows you to set a specific class for the last entry (as per the example, the 7th post). The code above, adds `no-margin-right` class to the last post in the output.
- In this line:

  ```
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img id="featured<?php echo $count; ?>" class="featured" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', true); ?>" /></a>
  ```

  `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', true); ?>` outputs the image URL you assigned to the post using the "image" custom field and its value (an image URL).
- Rest of the values I used are pretty standard. `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` outputs the permalink URL, `<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>` and `<?php the_title(); ?>` output the title of the post.

Here's an example of what you can pull off (you can actually do anything):

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

`get_posts()` is for 'secondary' loops - ones that exist along-side the main Loop, usually in a side-bar or at the bottom listing 'related' posts etc. `get_posts()` is called from within a template page. So it is the wrong thing to use here.

You'll want to alter the main query as outlined in: [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/50762#50762)

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse50857_alter_query');
function wpse50857_alter_query($query){

      //Check other conditionals depending on when you want to alter the loop
      if( $query->is_main_query() && is_home() ){

        $tax_query = array(array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'my-tag'
                      ));
        $query->set('tax_query',$tax_query);
        $query->set('posts_per_page',5);
      }
}
```

*Note this over-rides any previous `tax_query` (this doesn't matter in this context - but if it should you can get the previous `tax_query` and merge it with the new one...)*

[Other conditionals available here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

To edit how the posts are display, you'll need to edit the appropriate template page (`home.php`?, `front-page.php`?).

The loop will be something like:

```
if( have_posts() ):
    while( have_posts() ): the_post();
       //The loop 
      ?>
       <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
  <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
```

and you can edit that the display whatever you like.