# Display posts by tag on page

Tags: posts, pages, tags

I'm trying to create an advanced WordPress page that shows the regular content, plus a second section on the same page that shows the latest posts from X tag. For example, a page is created about "cats", has pictures, content, etc. Afterwords, I'd like to display the last X posts tagged with "cats". Is that possible without using plugins, and without creating a custom page template for every page?

Perhaps it's doable with the custom fields feature and multiple loops. E.g. get X amount of posts from a custom field with the value "cats". I've been struggling with it for a while now, can can't seem to find a solution that doesn't involve create a template for every single page.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually I asked a similar question in the past. Take a look at this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50857/10691

Comment: @AahanKrish But can you get it to work with custom fields to call the tags?

Comment: That may be possible, but I don't know how. :) You might want to wait a bit

Comment: You say get the latest posts from the same current tag listing? i.e. when browsing posts tagged 'cats', display the latest posts tagged/field 'cats' (tagged or field) ?

You can get the current query and use get_posts().[http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters]

Answer (score 4):

This should do the job. It'll check for posts that have been tagged with the title of the current page. There's no need to use `if (have_posts()):` on a page template: if the template is called it will be because there is a post :)

```
<div class="page-loop">

    <?php
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $page_title = strtolower(get_the_title());
        the_title('<h1>','</h1>');
      ?>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?><p>
    <?php endwhile;?>

</div>

<!-- Get the most recent post that has been tagged with the page title -->
<div class="related-posts">

    <?php
      $args = array(
        'tag' => $page_title,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
      );
      $query = new WP_Query($args);
      if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
          the_title('<h1>','</h1>');
        ?>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?><p>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
      <p>Sorry, no posts with this tag!</p>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>
```

If you'd rather use custom meta to add the 'tag' to the page (instead of just using the title) you could add a custom meta box to the page like so. Add the following code to your functions.php (nb: this will add the meta box to all pages)

```
/** register the meta box */
function my_theme_add_meta_boxes() {
    global $post;
    add_meta_box(
        'my-theme-meta',
        'Choose a tag',
        'my_theme_print_page_meta',
        'page',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_theme_add_meta_boxes');
/** Add extra meta to the page */
function my_theme_print_page_meta() {
    global $post;
    $page_tags = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_page-tags', true);
    ?>
    <label for="page-tags">Add a 'tag'</label>
    <input type="text" class="page-tags" name="page-tags" value="<?php echo esc_attr($page_tags); ?>" />
    <?php
}
/** Save post meta */
function my_theme_save_custom_meta() {
    global $post;

    // Stops WP from clearing post meta when autosaving
    if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
      return $post->ID;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['page-tags'])) {
        $clean = sanitize_text_field($_POST['page-tags']);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_page-tags', $clean);
    }

}
add_action('save_post', 'my_theme_save_custom_meta');
```

Then your page.php code could look like this:

```
<div class="page-loop">

    <?php
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $page_tags = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_page-tags', true);
        the_title('<h1>','</h1>');
      ?>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?><p>
    <?php endwhile;?>

</div>

<?php if ($page_tags): ?>

<!-- Get the most recent post that has been tagged with the page title -->
<div class="related-posts">

    <?php
      $args = array(
        'tag' => $page_tags,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
      );
      $query = new WP_Query($args);
      if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
          the_title('<h1>','</h1>');
        ?>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?><p>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
      <p>Sorry, no posts with this tag!</p>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>

<?php endif; // There are 'page tags' ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a WP_Query in the second part of your page:

```
<!-- First part of your page!-->
<div class="firstcontent">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?><p>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?><p>
    <?php endwhile; endif;?>

</div>

<!-- And now you call the WP_Query() !-->
<div class="secondcontent">

    <!-- get the main query !-->
    <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post'
    ));?>

    <!-- and you can use it as above !-->
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?><p>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?><p>
    <?php endwhile; endif;?>

</div>
```

I'm currently working with a theme on WordPress, and i'm actually doing this stuff, so it work !

Comment: Can you give an example in code?

Comment: yes wait two minutes i'm writing

Answer (score 0):

There are already answers above on how to use loops so I won't add more about [wp get recent posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) or [Taxonomy Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

But you might want to consider wrapping your code in a [Widget](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) which would make adding to your existing templates a little easier.